# Get-DscResource not returning full list when run from Jenkins on Windows

Tags: powershell, jenkins, windows-server-2016, dsc

I have a Windows Server 2016 Jenkins build box. I want to run some powershell in a Jenkins job.

As a test I have set the job to do this in a `Execute Windows batch command` build step:

`powershell -command Get-DscResource -module xhyper-v`

I get this output:

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\build-windows-server-2016-core>powershell -command Get-DscResource -module xhyper-v 
WARNING: There are no modules present in the system with the given module specification.
```

I even tried installing the PowerShell plugin and running it in a Powershell build step and I get the same result.

If I RDP onto the box and log on as the jenkins service account and open a cmd.exe window and run `powershell -command Get-DscResource -module xhyper-v`

I get this output:

```
C:\Users\svc_jenkins>powershell -command get-dscresource -module xhyper-v

ImplementedAs   Name                      ModuleName                     Version    Properties
-------------   ----                      ----------                     -------    ----------
PowerShell      xVHD                      xHyper-V                       3.6.0.0    {Name, Path, DependsOn, Ensure...}
PowerShell      xVhdFile                  xHyper-V                       3.6.0.0    {FileDirectory, VhdPath, CheckSu...
PowerShell      xVMHyperV                 xHyper-V                       3.6.0.0    {Name, VhdPath, DependsOn, Enabl...
PowerShell      xVMSwitch                 xHyper-V                       3.6.0.0    {Name, Type, AllowManagementOS, ...
```

Any ideas why Get-DscResource can't find xHyper-V module when run from a Jenkins job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Jenkins as 64-bit solved the issue.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34030153/38211

Thanks to help from ck on sqlcommunity.slack.com